# How do VLAN access ports and trunk ports work on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

I just spent half a day trying to figure out how to perform basic VLAN configuration on a Linux machine. I found some resources on the WEB, but from them it is not clear how to configure access port and trunk port on Linux machines. Some of the links:

[article on access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-vlan_on_bond_and_bridge_using_ip_commands)

[article on linuxjournal.com](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7268)

In the end I was able to create a "kind of" VLANed network next way, here is my network:

[Picture of Network with one VLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuE79.png)

2 client PC's (numbered 4 and 6) on top and 2 "PCs switches" (numbered 1 and 3) on the button

I want to be able to create several access ports with VLANs on KaliLinuxCLI_2-1 and KaliLinuxCLI_2-3 (currently there is only one port/VLAN for ease of explanation and configuration) and 1 trunk port between the PCs

I did next configurations:

- KaliLinuxCLI_2-4 and KaliLInuxCli_2-6 added IP addresses in the same netmask.
- KaliLinuxCLI_2-1 and KaliLinuxCLI_2-4:

Added a virtual interface with tag 10 for trunk interface eth3:

```
ip link add link eth3 name eth3.10 type vlan id 10
```

Created a bridge for vlan 10:

```
ip link add brvlan10 type bridge
```

Added trunk virtual interface eth3.10 and kind of "access" interface eth0, which I basically didn't configure at all to bridge brvlan10:

```
ip link set eth3.10 master brvlan10
ip link set eth0 master brvlan10
```

I also did turn on all of the interfaces by `ip link set <iface_name> up`

That's it. It did work:

- I was able to ping from KaliLinuxCLI_2-4 to KaliLinuxCLI_2-6
- I was able to see the tagged frames between KaliLinuxCLI_2-1 and KaliLinuxCLI_2-3
- I think I could have even added more PCs like KaliLinuxCLI_2-2 and 6 and added more VLANs in the way I did, and I am sure that it could work.

The thing that is bothering me is that the bridges does all the work here. Currently bridges are used to connect the "kind of" access ports (eth0) to the specific "trunk" interface with vlan so that frames are forwarded to the next PC.

How I think it should work is that an access port should be somehow configured with a vlan, so that the Linux PC switches the frame according to the vlan and destination MAC address, instead of blindly forwarding it where bridge wants to.

Is it possible on Linux configure an VLAN access ports like this? Is there a better way for basic VLAN configuration on Linux machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bridge *always* does the work, because the bridge *is* the closest equivalent of an Ethernet switch. ("MAC Bridge" is the actual term used by IEEE 802.1D, and so Ethernet switches are just a specific implementation of bridging.)

Therefore on Linux, the physical interfaces *must* belong to a 'bridge' interface in order for L2 frames to be forwarded. (It is wrong to think of the entire Linux system as a single giant switch, because you can have multiple bridges with completely independent L2 domains, each having its own "VLAN 10".)

That said, yes, on Linux you **can** configure per-port VLANs using the **`bridge vlan`** command. To use this configuration mode, first enable [VLAN filtering](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/09/14/vlan-filter-support-on-bridge/) on your bridge:

```
ip link set br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
```

Add both physical ports:

```
ip link set eth3 master br0
ip link set eth0 master br0
```

Finally add VLAN-to-port bindings:

```
bridge vlan add dev eth3 vid 10
bridge vlan add dev eth0 vid 10 pvid untagged
bridge vlan delete dev eth0 vid 1
```

This mode also has the advantage of correctly supporting (R)STP on the bridge.

---

Note: If you want the Linux host *itself* to participate in multiple VLANs, then you will still need 'vlan' interfaces, and you will also have to add the VLAN IDs to the filter (using the `self` keyword).

```
bridge vlan add dev br0 vid 10 self
ip link add br0.10 link br0 type vlan id 10
ip addr add x.x.x.x/xx dev br0.10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!

I will try out your configuration, but for me it seems reasonable!

Comment: It works like a charm!! This is the solution what I was looking for - no more per VLAN bridges and VLAN interfaces